# c# For loop through 2D array exception unhandled, Index out of bounds

Tags: c#

Apologies for the beginner question but I am struggling to find an answer as to why I get an exception unhandled error after the first For loop. It runs through the loop once, asking me the three questions, and then the program stops. C#

(I am trying to teach myself as my teachers aren't going through much at all, so sorry again)

```
Console.WriteLine("How many people do you have to enter?");
        int numPeople = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string[,] data = new string[numPeople,2];

        for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Name:");
            data[i,0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter " + data[i,0] +"'s Age:");
            data[i,1] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter " + data[i,0] + "'s class:");
            data[i,2] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        for (int v = 0; v < numPeople; v++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data[v,x] + "\t");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You declared `string[numPeople,2];` with the second index size = 2, but the loop uses a size of 3: `for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)`. `x = { 0, 1, 2 }`. See also [Tutorial: Learn to debug using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/getting-started-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017).

Comment: When you declare the array you are specifying only 2 elements for each person, but you are adding 3 elements in the `for` loop.

Comment: That was a really silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: We all were silly beginners once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part

```
string[,] data = new string[numPeople,2];
```

you define that your array size is 2
and the error it gives is `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`

So you change the

`string[,] data = new string[numPeople,2];`

to

```
`string[,] data = new string[numPeople,3];
```

Read more about the subject from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-arrays/ and try to understand how the arrays work. :)

also if you are using Visual Studio read about the Break point debugging 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017

Happy coding!